# Android share button in action bar no scrolling

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I have share button in action menu but when I click "show all" the menu is open and I am can not scrolling the list. why?

The code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share)
                .getActionProvider();
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(doShare());

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
 public Intent doShare() {
            // populate the share intent with data
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Google play Link");
            return intent;
        }
```

The main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/share"
         android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionProviderClass=
            "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

Comment: I tested the code, for me it is working maybe you have to look somewhere else. Might be a problem with representation of the share dialog.

Comment: What I can do with it?